# How to import a HTTPotion into an elixir project

Tags: http, elixir

I created an project:

```
$ mix new sample
```

I edited the `mix.exs` file:

```
defmodule Sample.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :sample,
     version: "0.1.0",
     elixir: "~> 1.3",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps()]
  end

  def application do
    [applications: [:logger, :httpotion]]
  end

  defp deps do
    [{:httpotion, "~> 3.0.2"}]
  end
end
```

and my `samplex.ex` file:

```
defmodule Sample do
  IO.puts "Hello World"
end
```

I run:

```
$ mix deps.get
$ mix
```

and I get:

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Hello World
Generated sample app
```

until here all perfect, but if I change the sample.ex to:

```
defmodule Sample do
  HTTPotion.get "httpbin.org/get"
end
```

I get the following error:

```
$ mix deps.get
Running dependency resolution
All dependencies up to date
$ mix         
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: variable response is unused
  lib/sample.ex:2


== Compilation error on file lib/sample.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:ibrowse_lb, {'httpbin.org', 80})
    /Users/xxx/sample/deps/ibrowse/src/ibrowse.erl:328: :ibrowse.send_req/6
    lib/httpotion.ex:355: HTTPotion.request/3
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

what is missing? I have no experience with elixir.

Comment: Try adding `:httpotion` in `applications` in `mix.exs`: `[applications: [:logger, :httpotion]]`.

Comment: thank you @Dogbert I updated the question but the error is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced the issue with provided steps.
`HTTPotion.get/2` raises exception if called directly in the module
but works fine if called from the function.

```
defmodule Sample do
  def request do
    HTTPotion.get "httpbin.org/get"
  end
end
```

Checked with test

```
defmodule SampleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "response from HTTPotion" do
    assert Sample.request
  end
end
```

I think it raises exception if called in compile time.